# How to add a Navigation Controller with Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

**1. Step:** Create a new UIViewController:
- Xcode -> New File... -> Cocoa Touch Class -> UIViewController
- Name: MyViewController

**2. Step:** Drag and drop a "Navigation Controller" (UINavigationController) from the Library to MyViewController.xib

[image]

**3.Step:** I'm sure, I have to do something to connect the Navigation Controller correctly, isn't it?

**4.Step:** Try to start the new View Controller as a modal dialog:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"navContr: %@", myViewController.navigationController);
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: myViewController animated:YES];
```

Result: "navContr: nil"

**5.Step:** You can see the new modal view (MyViewController), but there's no NavigationController and no UINavigationBar.

Thank you very much for your help!

---

**UPDATE 1:**

**6.Step:** I set a new UIViewController (ViewNavi2) as "Root View Controller":
[image]

**7.Step:** I define a `IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController` in the class MyViewController and configure the xib: Navigation Controller -> Connections -> Referencing Outlets

But my Navigation Controller is still nil :-(

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"navContr: %@", myViewController.navigationController);
// -> "navContr: nil"
```

Comment: [here](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-add-navigation-controller-in.html) is the simple tutorial for adding Navigation controller

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also wanted to include the navigation controller in the NIB file, but all that the Apple documentation said was that it is "not optimal" without actually explaining how to do it.  I wanted my main tabbed window to call up a modal window containing the typical navigation controls without defining the navigation controller programmatically.  I'll share how I did it.

Your code was very similar to mine, as I also defined an `IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController` in MyViewController.  From Interface Builder, I simply defined my view in the root view controller and set the File's Owner->view to that view definition.

And similarly to your code, I did the following in my parent window:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

(I am calling presentModelViewController on self, I don't know why you had `self.navigationController`.) When I tested this, the result was that my view was loaded from the NIB file, but the navigation bar was missing.  One more line of code in MyViewController fixed this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setView:myNavigationController.view];

}
```

All I am doing here, is setting MyViewController's view to point to myNavigationController.view, which contains everything that was defined in the NIB file, including the navigation controller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer! I'm sure that this will help a lot of people! :-) @all: please VOTE UP

Comment: @Henry I tried to do something very similar. This saved me a lot of work. Thanks!

Comment: Very beautiful explanation.Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an image of the xib file? Are we suppose to have one View (who is the owner of the view) and another UINavigationController at the topmost level? Then where would our actual ui objects go to, under the UINavigationController's view or the original View?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the template in XCode for a "Navigation-based Application". (New Project -> Navigation-based Application) Then open up the MainWindow.xib in Interface Builder. Though it is not a view, think of it as the viewcontroller that you created in step 1. Then look at the "Root View Controller" that is referenced in the inspector and see how it is connected to the "Root View Controller" nib in the Attributes inspector and the "RootViewController" Class in the Identity inspector.

You will want to put the content you want to display at the root of your navigation in your version of a "RootViewController". Typically, the controller that is displayed next is a "DetailViewController". Again, read through the example code that the template provides and you will see how to start on that. Look at the commented code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in the example template of the RootViewController.m. You will need to create your own view controller to serve as the DetailViewController.

Hopefully this will clear things up for you.

//EDITS based on your Comment//
The Apple docs say that if you want to use IB to make your Navigation controllers you should really put them in your MainWindow.xib. I was tinkering with the fact that you cannot have the NavigationController as a subview of your UIView object. What you can do given where you've started from is to use IB to add a Navigation bar object to your view controller and then control things from there.

From the Apple documentation "Although you could also load standalone or modally presented navigation controllers from your main nib file (or any other nib file), doing so is not optimal. In those scenarios, it is usually easier to create the navigation controller programmatically at the point of use."

//MORE EDITS//
In XCode4 the project template is now called a "Master Detail" project. This is because it will be set up as a split view controller in iPad but still a regular navigation project in iPhone. Where I reference "RootViewController" in the answer, you will now find something called "MasterViewController"

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I analyze the Navigation-based Application carefully. Yes, there is a MainWindow.xib with a working Navigation Controller. It is connected with the AppDelegate, that's the only difference to my MyViewController. In the template project, you can't see how MainWindow.xib gets initialized and maybe my code "MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];" is wrong. Please look "UPDATE 1" in my question.

Comment: From the Apple documentation "Although you could also load standalone or modally presented navigation controllers from your main nib file (or any other nib file), doing so is not optimal. In those scenarios, it is usually easier to create the navigation controller programmatically at the point of use."

Comment: Yes, you're right, it would be easier to create the navigation controller programmatically, but I have to do this with Interface Builder. The reason you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604647/how-to-create-an-uiviewcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-with-interface-buil Do you still have some ideas for me?

Comment: In the other question you mention, it looks like you got the view controller/navigation controller to work when you put it into a MainWindow.xib. What I would suggest is running the one that works that way through the nifty nib2objc (https://github.com/akosma/nib2objc) software. This should give you some objective C files you can look at to see how the different elements are created and related to each other.

Comment: Apple has removed the ability to make that project from Xcode4 - even though you still have to do it for all iOS 4.0/4.1/4.2 projects. It would be helpful if you could link to an example project, or explain WHAT EXACTLY is happening in that project

Comment: The new version of that project is called a "Master Detail" project. I will edit the answer. The old RootView is now MasterView.

Answer (score 0):

The next code is will not give you any valid object.

```
NSLog(@"navContr: %@", myViewController.navigationController);
```

The reason is because navigationController property of UIViewController [only returns a navigation controller if the view controller is in its stack. This property is nil if a navigation controller cannot be found.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Your view controller is not in the stack of the navigation controller. Anyway I even am not sure if you correctly initialize our navigation controller. Read some documentation.

Comment: Thank you for you help, too! It seams, that "the view controller is not in its stack". Yes, I think that I don't have correctly initialize my navigation controller. But how can I do that in Interface Builder? I update my question, please have a look on "UPDATE 1".

Comment: Also, if your view IS in the nav controller stack but you (auto)released it somewhere you shouldn't have, self.navigationController might be nil. Doh!