# Weird behaviour of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

After hours of unsuccessful research, here is my questions.

Since the beginning of my app development, `navigationBar.topItem.title` doesn't work, so that I decided to create my own subclass, and there's still a problem.

Here is my code :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

  if (self) {

    NSLog(@"NavBar Ready !");

    self.topItem.title = @"something";

    NSLog(@"%@", self.class);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.topItem.class);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.topItem.title.class);


  }
 return self;
}
```

### Edit

Here is the console output, as you can see, there's a problem with the `topItem`class, but this property is a **read-only** so I can't `alloc` and `init` any `UINavigationItem` for it.

```
2014-03-13 17:25:34.063 CCE[63471:60b] NavBar Ready !
2014-03-13 17:25:34.064 CCE[63471:60b] CCENavigationBar
2014-03-13 17:25:34.065 CCE[63471:60b] (null)
2014-03-13 17:25:34.065 CCE[63471:60b] (null)
```

So here is my question... **What's happenning, and What can I do to solve it ?**

*Thanks You SO Community !*

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the built-in one not working manifests itself?  Can you show us the code for how you are calling the built-in one?  Typically Apple's frameworks do work.

Comment: Well, with the good method I guess, in my `UINavigationController` `viewDidLoad` method I call `self.navigationBar.topItem.title`and pass it a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects (using storyboards) with ViewControllers embedded in a NavigationController if I set:

```
self.title= @"title";
```

That sets the title of the navigation bar. Have you tried setting it that way?

Comment: No, I try and give you feedBack, it could work (but I didn't precise that I don't use storyboard on this project). **EDIT** : Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(

Comment: If you did it by adding a UINavigationBar, I just tried adding one and creating it's property `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navController;` Then using the same `self.navController.topItem.title = @"Test";` that worked for me to.

Comment: This situation sounds similar to whats happening: [How to add a Navigation Controller with Interface Builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670528/how-to-add-a-navigation-controller-with-interface-builder)

Comment: I don't use storyboard on this project :/
I'm pretty sure that I have to do something with the (null) that `...topItem.class` returns

Comment: did you try with this ?        `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"title"`

Comment: **Damn, it works !** How the hell didn't I think to that ! Huge Thanks Boy :)